# How, when you bind data to a collection, do you set it to a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

Say what I have is an `ObservableCollection<People> ListOfPeople` such that:

```cs
public class People
{
    public string Name { get; set; };
}
```

I have a combobox written equivilent to:

```cs
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox_Profiles" Text="Select Person"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=???}">
```

How can I set the items within the combobox to be the value of each `Name` property? I thought I knew how to do this, but I clearly do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select what to show in the case of a single property use the `DisplayMemberPath` and set it to `Name`.

You can also set the `SelectedValuePath` if you want the control to return a specific property of the object rather than the object itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has done the trick!